# Why are either mmv or rename changing multiple file names on Fedora 35?

Tags: linux, rename, fedora

On my Fedora 35 system neither of the following are working.
I have about twenty or so jpg files in a directory, and I wish to add the name of a website to each image after its main title.
I am certain that on Linux Mint the rename command worked perfectly, whereas the mmv I downloaded in case there was some problem on Fedora returns a 'no match...Nothing done' error.

```
 mmv '*.jpg' '-new-suffix.jpg'
```

or

```
  rename 's/\.jpg/-new-suffix.jpg/g' *jpg
```

I have checked the permissions on all files - they are 777 - and the directory itself also has 777 permissions.

I was expecting to see a list of files ending in ...-new-suffix.jpg but nothing has been changed with either of these commands.

Comment: What exactly means "neither of the following are working"? What files do you have? What result do you expect? What result do you actually get?

Comment: I have a load of jpg files. When I use the rename function, I just get a new prompt, i.e. no return message, but nothing has been changed. When using the mmv command - which I only really want to use if rename won't work on my system - I get that 'no match' message.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `.jpg` should be `*.jpg`. See the examples [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. Show an example of the files you have. From your description "I have a load of jpg files" we cannopt see if you might have made a mistake. Copy&paste the exact command and the output or error message, don't retype.

Comment: You must be doing it in a wrong directory, what does `ls *jpg` show?

Comment: ls *jpg shows a list of all the jpg files I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing mmv's capture marker.The correct syntax for the `mmv` command reads so:

```
   mmv '*.jpg' '#1-new-suffix.jpg'
```

See this link for a fuller rundown of mmv's syntax: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html